# Removing all elements execpt the first one in list pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, in which in one column I have a list of hashtags. Now, I would like to delete all elements in that list expect the first one of each row.
Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do so:

```
df.hashtags = df.hashtags.map(lambda l: l[:1])
```